# Optimising WHERE subquery inside JOIN subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, join, optimization, subquery

```
SELECT journey.departure AS startTime, departure.duration AS seconds, ADDTIME(journey.departure, departure.duration) AS departureTime, p.section
FROM journey
JOIN journey_day ON journey_day.journey = journey.id
JOIN pattern p ON p.id = journey.pattern
JOIN (
    SELECT departure.section, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(time)) AS duration
    FROM pattern_link departure
    WHERE departure.from_sequence < (SELECT from_sequence FROM pattern_link WHERE from_stop = "1980SN12532B" AND section = departure.section)
    GROUP BY departure.section
) departure ON departure.section = p.section
WHERE journey.service = "44-A-A-y10-1" AND p.direction = "inbound" AND journey_day.day = 4
GROUP BY journey.id
ORDER BY departure
```

This query takes absolutely ages to run. This is because of the subquery in the `WHERE` clause inside the `JOIN` subquery. The problem is, I'm not sure how else to write it. In the `WHERE` statement in the departure join I need to know the `from_sequence` number (basically an ID) and the only way I can do that is by querying based on the criteria in the WHERE clause.

Any ideas?

Comment: use join instead of subquery in the join subquery?? Is there any relation between pattern_link and pattern_link_departure?

Comment: @Torrezzzz I'll try that, not sure what you mean about pattern_link_departure, if you look again youll see that departure ist just an alias for the pattern_link table

Comment: My bad didnt notice that...Use join it may fasten the query a little bit....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version would benefit from an index on `pattern_link(section, from_stop, time)`.  That index might be the easiest way to improve the query.

You can also try writing this as an explicit `join` by using aggregation:

```
SELECT departure.section, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(time)) AS duration
FROM pattern_link departure JOIN
     (SELECT section, from_sequence
      FROM pattern_link
      WHERE from_stop = '1980SN12532B'
     ) s
     ON s.section = departure.section
WHERE departure.from_sequence < s.from_sequence
GROUP BY departure.section
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Is there any way you'd be able to adjust your query so that it still contains the original `FROM journey`, or have you removed that to show that that should be done in a separate query?

Comment: @jskidd3 . . . This is intended to be just the subquery, which was the basis of your question.